# syslog config for sftp logging

Tags: logging, freebsd, sftp

I'm on FreeBSD11. I changed syslog config file to log sftp actions in a file, but it doesn't work.

**/etc/ssh/sshd_config**

```
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server -f LOCAL5 -l INFO
```

**/etc/syslog.conf**

```
local5.info                                        /var/log/sftp/sftp.log
```

Then I restart the services, but any action saved in sftp.log and it's empty.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you using `chroot`? What OpenSSH version is there?

Comment: Yes,OpenSSH_7.2p2 by running ssh -v.

Answer (score 3):

This never worked in OpenSSH upstream package. It is for several reasons:

- You don't have `/dev/log` socket that is used to send log messages to the `syslog` (if you have, you didn't mention it in the question)
- There is possibility to use the "parent" process socket that is not in chroot to log your events, but

  - in that case, you would need a modification to the OpenSSH code ([upstream bug](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2681)) and set up [as we do it in Red Hat](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/341501/setting-up-logging-for-chroot-users/341525#341525).
  - you would need to use `internal-sftp` instead

Answer (score 1):

Check

- whether your `sftp-server` PATH is correct (by `locate sftp-server`). I suppose it should be `/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server` instead of `/usr/libexec/sftp-server`.
- if `/var/log/sftp/`and `/var/log/sftp/sftp.log`exists – with correct permissions.

Comment: /usr/libexec/sftp-server is the path and I don't have openssh on my system.The permission is 755.